# Using an array to pass arguments to a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments

Let's say I have some code that looks like this:

```
var x_1 = "something";
var x_2 = "something";
var x_3 = "something";
.
.
.
var x_n = "something";
var parameters = [ x_1, x_2, x_3, …, x_n ];
someFunction.apply(this, parameters);
```

Can my `x_1, x_2, x_3, …., x_n` in the `parameters` array each be a declared variable somewhere in the code like in the example above? Or does the parameters array can only look like this

```
var parameters = ["something", "something", "something", …, "something" ];
someFunction.apply(this, parameters);
```

Meaning having only the values of the `x_1, x_2, x_3, …, x_n` variables and not the variables themselves.

I would like to use the `var parameters = [ x_1, x_2, x_3, …, x_n ];` option so if this doesn’t work like in the example above or/and there is a better way to do it, then I would like to hear it.

Comment: What a strange question. If you'd tried it, you'd have seen that it works just fine.

Comment: FYI, you don't even need an array. You can use `someFunction.call(this, x_1, x_2, x_3, ..., x_n)`

Comment: @Phil I just wanted to clarify it so a simple yes would be enough. In my code the input variables change in numbers so I’m going to use an array to create the variables that contain the input values dynamically, therefore `someFunction.call(this, x_1, x_2, x_3, ..., x_n)` won't do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You could have tried it!**

Anyway, not only this,

```
var parameters = ["something", "something", "something", …, "something" ];
someFunction.apply(this, parameters);
```

even this,

```
someFunction.apply(this, ["something", "something", "something", …, "something" ]);
```

..is perfectly alright.